ssh-keygen is not reading stdin to get an encryption password (or: what is ssh-askpass?)
I'm automating key generation with ssh-keygen (OpenSSH v8.9), on a headless server. This is straightforward if no password is required, but gets difficult if you do need a password. ssh-keygen needs 3 things on stdin when generating a new key: y, because the keyfile already exists, and the required password, repeated twice.
With some simplification I'm doing this as follows:
$ printf -v input "y\npassword\npassword\n"
$ echo -n "$input"
y
password
password
$ echo -n "$input" | ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a100 -f tmpkey

When I initially did this I got this output:
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
tmpkey already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

The key pair was created, but the private key wasn't encrypted. So, I installed ssh-askpass, on a test system with X. When I run ssh-keygen now, I get an OpenSSH authentication popup, and stdin is now ignored. Obviously, I can't have a graphical popup on a headless server, even if I wanted it.
So what's going on? Can I persuade ssh-keygen to automate password entry? If not, can I perhaps use openssl to add a password, or even create the file? I do want to get an OpenSSH-format key out of this - I'm already automating PKCS#8 with openssl.
EDIT
I've found the SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE envvar for ssh (not ssh-keygen). If I set it to 'never', it does stop the ssh-askpass popup, but ssh-keygen now only reads the first line of stdin, and ignores the password on the next two lines. So, it doesn't get me anywhere.

ssh-keygen reads passphrase from stdin ONLY if it's a tty (in practice a pty) otherwise, as you saw, it tries unless prohibited to use Xwindows ssh-askpass; if you were using commandline as you posted expect would give you a pty, but you've now disclosed you're not and writing your own pty code will be some work. Alternatively puttygen, if available for or built on your Unix, can generate OpenSSH 'new' format with passphrase from file -- and /dev/stdin works for me. (Although it recently had a serious flaw in the generation for ecdsa/P-521!)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401711/expect-rsa-key-generation-using-expect-script-is-not-working

@dave_thompson_085 - thanks - I'm just trying it out now. I think, after a quick scan of CVE-2024-31497 and the description in the PuTTY wishlist, that this is just a PuTTY (and not PuTTYgen) issue, so there's no point compiling a recent PuTTYgen from source.

You're right; I forgot the problem was in signing 'k' not keygen

You can instead generate the key using PuTTYgen, as dave_thompson_085 pointed out in the comments. Spoiler: you probably don't want to do this, as puttygen appears to have incomplete OpenSSH support.
This will get you an OpenSSH private key:
prikey=$(echo "$password" | puttygen -q -t ed25519 -C '' -O private-openssh-new -o /dev/stdout --new-passphrase /dev/stdin)

The passphrase is on stdin, and the key goes to stdout, so there's nothing recorded in your bash history, or in the ps output. You can now get the public key as:
 tmppipe=$(mktemp -u)
 mkfifo -m 600 "$tmppipe"
 echo "$prikey" > "$tmppipe" &
 pubkey=$(echo "$password" | puttygen "$tmppipe" --old-passphrase /dev/stdin -O public-openssh)

So far, this is way better than ssh-keygen. However, the fly in the ointment is -a100. The procedure above generates a key file with the default 16 KDF rounds.
The puttygen docs (actually the man page; there are no written docs, I think) aren't clear on setting the number of KDF rounds, but it looks like you can set this with --ppk-param passes=$rounds. This does appear to work if you're generating a PuTTY PPK file, but doesn't work for an OpenSSH file. puttygen doesn't complain, but the key file still shows 16 rounds, and making rounds a big number makes no difference to the time required to decrypt the key. To find the number of rounds coded in the file, see Gilles' answer here.
Unless I've missed something in the man page, this makes puttygen pretty pointless for generating OpenSSH keys with passphrases. I personally would use ssh-keygen and hope no-one's looking when you're making the keys. As far as I can make out, you also can't use puttygen for changing the comment in the key file.

The way to provide the password is using -N:
echo y| ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a100 -N "$input" -f tmpkey

Of course you should provide the variable input with content like yours:
input=password


Unfortunately, that's not secure; the password is visible in ps/etc. -N would be good if it could read from a file/fifo/stdin, but it seems that it can't.

@QF0, the same is true about your idea with print command. AFAIK there is no 100% secure way to provide password in shell.

Yes, you're right; that's why I said 'with some simplification'. I didn't want to confuse the issue with extra details. In the actual script, the password is sent from C code on stdin. The equivalent openssl script reads this by cating stdin to a variable and then -pass stdin <<<$password. My current openssh version also cats stdin to a variable, and builds up the input with printf. Since printf is a built-in I think this is "secure".

@QF0, if you deal with variables the situation is similar to ps. You can get the environment variables with values from /proc directory. But consider the fact time to run the script is short so will be not so easy catch the moment.

@QF0, as you run script on the host why do not generate in advance set of keys and upload them to the host(s). You can build relatively secure environment where to generate them w/o fear of sniffing.

Unfortunately, the keys aren't for me. Arbitrary users download a new key pair, do something with the private key, and then upload the public key. It would obviously be better if they could generate their own key pairs, but the users are generally not Linux-literate. This of course leaves me with the huge problem of 'securely' generating private keys for them.
